# Getting a core segmentation fault when trying to read a file from argv[]

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

I have been getting a core segmentation fault when trying to read a file from argv[]. I have created the file and I am very sure that I am trying to access the correct memory address. However, when trying to open the file I receive the core dump.

Here is the relavent code-

```
  for (int x=1;x<argc;x++){
  int buffsize=2056;
  char buff[buffsize];
  FILE* thefile;
  thefile=fopen("argv[x]","r");
  if (thefile == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s cannot open file '%s'\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    return 2;
  }
```

The command line argument I am passing in is

`./words testfile.txt`

with ./words being the compiled code.

I actually found the solution, it seems to be the quotes in argv in the fopen, why is this?

Comment: Are you passing it via the command line ? Can you post the command line arguments ?

Comment: Debug 101: The file open fails, so the first thing to do is `printf` the file name on the line before the `open` to see what file is failing.

Answer (score 3):

Oops! I believe the line

```
thefile=fopen("argv[x]","r");
```

Should be:

```
thefile=fopen(argv[x],"r");
```

This is because `"argv[x]"` is not code, it's a string. What's that? Is that a path to a file? It's not compiled as code. It doesn't refer to one of the arguments in `argv`.

You might also want your log message to use that filename. Notice the `argv[x]`:

```
fprintf(stderr, "%s cannot open file '%s'\n", argv[0], argv[x]);
```